# adding dynamic data to mysql with php j query

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

I am trying to add multileg travel information using PHP, jQuery and MySQL. I present to users with existing data and then they dynamically add travel leg information to their existing visit. What I have done so far is below.

1. Bind data (PHP -MySQL) to the HTML table. Show add new button the user.
2. When the user clicks on add new, I have used jQuery to clone the data and this has dynamic id.
3. On the form there is file upload as well which needs to upload the file and also save information in the database.

My problem is how can I rebind the data on the table without effecting any other thing. I have tried to use jQuery load but it tries to reload the entire page rather than just reloading the newly generated trs.

I am open to change my logic on the whole as to how I do this.

Appreciate any help on this.

Comment: some of your code would be helpful so we can see you tried :)

Comment: This is a javascript related topic, not php specific. You need to write the bind on the wrapper of your new trs are loaded in, not the tr itself. Otherwise, trigger an event that unbinds and then newly binds all the new trs. [Try looking here](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to find out how to write the former.

Comment: Is there anyway where i can upload my code as a text document as , i can't paste it here. I wouldn't just bluff anyway....